# How to convert and use JSON data from a remote Wordpress server?

Tags: api, json, server, remote

I got this code

```
add_action( 'init', 'check_api_data' );

function check_api_data() {    

  if(isset($_GET['api']) ) {
  if ($_GET['api'] == 'json'){
           $args = array(  
                'post_type' => 'post'
           );
           $query = new WP_Query( $args ); // $query is the WP_Query Object
           $posts = $query->get_posts();   // $posts contains the post objects

           $output = array();
           foreach( $posts as $post ) {    // Pluck the id and title attributes
               $output[] = array( 
                'id' => $post->ID, 
                'title' => $post->post_title, 
                'content' => $post ->post_content,
                'imageurl' => wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) )
                );
           }
           header("Content-type: application/json");
           echo json_encode( $output );
       }
   exit();
   }  
}
```

This is the output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 19,
    "title": "Early bird tickets",
    "content": "that is good",
    "imageurl": "http://localhost/PRACTISE/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/news2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 95,
    "title": "See you next year!",
    "content": "Lorem ipsum",
    "imageurl": "http://localhost/PRACTISE/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/tak_for_i_aar.jpg"
  }
]
```

How can I use this data in a remote server, so that everytime I update my content of *Server A* it gets updated at *Server B*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On server B:

```
$result = wp_remote_post('http://serverA.com/?api=json', array(
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'redirection' => 1,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking'    => true,
    'headers'     => array(),
    'body'        => array(),
    'cookies'     => array()
));
if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
    return 'bad connection!';
}
$json = $result['body'];
$posts = json_decode($json);
```

Now you have $posts as usual php array. `var_dump($posts)` will look like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#7918 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(19)
    ["title"]=>
    string(18) "Early bird tickets"
    ["content"]=>
    string(12) "that is good"
    ["imageurl"]=>
    string(65) "http://localhost/PRACTISE/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/news2.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#7919 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(95)
    ["title"]=>
    string(18) "See you next year!"
    ["content"]=>
    string(11) "Lorem ipsum"
    ["imageurl"]=>
    string(73) "http://localhost/PRACTISE/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/tak_for_i_aar.jpg"
  }
}
```

Comment: You solved my problem, thanks!
Just one questions?
Why is it that even though we have GOT posts from the remote server we have to use the POST method? instead of the GET?

Comment: It works  if I set the 'method' to GET though

Comment: So the array is an optional one
But Why did u overwrite the default values? (I dont know what the default values are though)

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, we can use POST. My answer is an extraction from one of my plugins, so you can edit it. Maybe overwriting of defaults is overkill ))

Comment: Last question, what does the `$json = $result['body'];` do?

Comment: wp_remote_get returns a lot of info: headers, cookies, body. All as $result array. You should get json string sent from server A into $json var, to decode it later. Make var_dump of the $result and you will see it by yourself. Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get

Comment: Yeah it makes sense, but why is it that if I write `$result = wp_remote_get($url,
 array(
 'body' => array( 'id' => '11')
    )

);`
it DOESNT overwrite? it prints the the original as usual even though I wanted it to overwrite the body element?

Why DOESNT all of their ids = 11?

Comment: Because it is different arrays. In wp_remote_get you specify the body of your http REQEST to serverA, in result you have body of http RESPONSE from serverA. For more info, you shoud read about http requests.